# Как вывести время в HTML?

Tags: javascript

```
var qw = new Date;
```

Как вывести переменную `qw` на HTML и чтобы часы работали в реальном времени?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Comment: Расширьте объяснения того, что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге. Вы хотите вывести реальное время в какой-то произвольный блок HTML? Или вам достаточно получить ответ через консоль? В любом случае, пройдите по ссылке выше и проработайте этот вопрос. Готовые ответы вас сильно не продвинут в освоении JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function timeBegan() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();

  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('timeNow').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    timeBegan()
  }, 500);
}
timeBegan();
```

```html
<div id="timeNow"></div>
```

Comment: Странно, что за массовое минусование ? ))

Comment: тролли. Лови плюс

Comment: Я тоже недавно получил минусов за подобный вопрос. Сам вопрос такой, тут уж ничего не поделаешь. Ловите  обое по "+". Вопрос может быть так себе, но ответы у вас обоих отличные на него.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var time = document.getElementById('my_time');
 setInterval(function(){
   var d = new Date();
   time.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() 
 }, 950);
```

```html
<div id='my_time'></div>
```

Comment: Троллей - поймать и пальчики повыдёргивать )) +1

Comment: @Arsen, это недостаток интернета и анонимности ;-)

Comment: такую не рабочую фигню я и сам могу написать

Comment: @Rad, если руки кривые не моя проблема. Нажми на выполнить и оно все работает

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Clock {
  static timeNormalize(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
  }
  static getTime() {
    let date = new Date();

    let h = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getHours());
    let m = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getMinutes());
    let s = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getSeconds());

    return `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  }
  static RENDER_FACTORY_DEFAULT(element) {
    element.innerHTML = Clock.getTime();
  }
  constructor(element, renderFactory = Clock.RENDER_FACTORY_DEFAULT) {
    let update = () => {
      renderFactory(element);

      window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    update();
  }
}

let clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
let clock = new Clock(clockElement);
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>
```

В случаи если приложение `spa`, то при удалении элемента `.clock` из дом-дерева, а также заnullевание ссылки на экземпляр `Clock`, произойдет утечка, так как его удерживает `requestAnimationFrame`. Поэтому нужно реализовать функционал утилизации (в данном случаи стоп).

```js
class Toggle {
  constructor(isToggle = false) {
    this.isToggle = isToggle;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isToggle = !this.isToggle;
  }
}

class Clock {
  static timeNormalize(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
  }
  static getTime() {
    let date = new Date();

    let h = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getHours());
    let m = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getMinutes());
    let s = Clock.timeNormalize(date.getSeconds());

    return `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  }
  static RENDER_FACTORY_DEFAULT(element) {
    element.innerHTML = Clock.getTime();
  }
  constructor(element, renderFactory = Clock.RENDER_FACTORY_DEFAULT) {
    let toggle = new Toggle(false);
    let updateInfo = {
      updateId: null
    };

    this.start = () => {
      if (!toggle.isToggle) {
        toggle.toggle();

        update();
      }
    }
    this.stop = () => {
      if (toggle.isToggle) {
        toggle.toggle();

        if (updateInfo.updateId) {
          window.cancelAnimationFrame(updateInfo.updateId);
        }
      }
    }

    let update = () => {
      renderFactory(element);


      if (toggle.isToggle) {
        updateInfo.updateId = window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }
    }
  }
}


let clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
let clock = new Clock(clockElement);
clock.start();
```

```html
<div class="clock">
</div>
```